# Open a program as administrator with conditions (e.g. /h or something)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want to run a program with PowerShell using `Start-Process` in a batch but with conditions.

I tested it and I ran `cmd /c` using the `Start-Process` command.

Command:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process `cmd /c` -Verb runas"
```

It didn't work.

So I tested it on PowerShell. Tried the same command and it returned this error:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'runas'.
At line:1 char:14
+ Start-Process <<<<  'cmd /c' -Verb runas
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

How can I make this work on batch using `powershell` command and on the main PowerShell?

Comment: `powershell -command "start-process \`cmd /c\`  runas"`

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make the actual program launched be launched in admin context, if you don't find the answer you are looking for here explore running Scheduled Tasks.

Comment: `powershell -command "start-process cmd /c -verb runas"`

Comment: should be simple

`Start-Process cmd /c –Verb RunAs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backtick is PowerShell's escape character. In a statement

```
Start-Process `cmd /c` -Verb runas
```

the backticks escape the `c` of `cmd` and the space following the `/c`. The former isn't problematic, because it just makes the `c` a literal `c` (which it is anyway). However, escaping the space between `/c` and `-Verb` effectively turns the whole sequence `/c -Verb` into a single string. Basically it's the same as if you'd run this statement:

```
Start-Process cmd "/c -Verb" runas
```

Since [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-3.0) accepts only 2 positional parameters (`-FilePath` and `-ArgumentList`) everything else must be passed via named parameters. Hence the error about no positional parameter accepting the argument `runas`.

Run the command like this:

```
Start-Process cmd /c, dir, "$env:windir\temp" -Verb runas
```

or

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/c', 'dir', "$env:windir\temp" -Verb runas
```

or like this (from CMD):

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process cmd /c, dir, \"$env:windir\temp\" -Verb runas"
```

and it will work as you'd expect.

---

**Edit**
Since apparently it wasn't clear enough initially: the argument for the `-ArgumentList` parameter is a comma-separated list (an array).

```
Start-Process cmd /c, dir, "$env:windir\temp" -Verb runas
#                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                       this right here
```

Comment: Using your explanations, I was able to run a powershell script, as administrator, via batch file. Two situations occur: 1 - I can't execute passing parameter. 2 - The powershell screen appears for a few seconds before the script is finished. I try:
`PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""D:\z_Batchs and Scripts\Batchs\LUFS_Normalize\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}" ps1'"' %_vLUF%` I need to pass the parameter and the powershell screen does not appear.